# Quoting vs Citing

Tags: differences

When you would use the words "quoting" and when "citing" , where "quote" and where "citation"?

Comment: +1 My poor russian translates "to quote" as "tzitirovatʲ", which is transliteration of "to cite".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Citation: You refer to particular resource. You read a passage from a journal and express it using your own words.
Quotation: Copy Paste. For example common phrases.

Answer (score 7):

When talking about reporting what someone has said or done, in an academic situation, a citation or citing does not necessarily require a quotation, in which instance a citation is synonymous with a reference.

But there are other differences between a citation and a quotation.

In America, police issue citations for various offences. They do not issue quotations.

A citation is also any form of commendation or award, although I think this is typically American usage.

Contractors will tender quotes or quotations for how much a job will cost. The don't tender citations.

Related to that, stock market prices are called quotations.

For more information see [citation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/citation) and [quotation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quotation)

Comment: That's some fun to read, for sure)

Answer (score 5):

Citing is more formal and used when you refer to a source for a section or point in your document. 
You cite to strengthen your point.
Citing need not use the exact words in the source.

Quoting can be both formal or informal. 
You quote a source to disclaim personal responsibility.
Quotes are verbatim to some degree you can strategically leave out parts of the quote (All those protestations of being misquoted in the media arise out of this!)